# Script the granting of server roles to a SQL Server Login

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-security

I have a script that creates a login in SQL Server as follows:

```
CREATE LOGIN [MyDomain\MyUser] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master],
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

Is it possible to add to this script the granting of server roles? I want to grant the sysadmin server role to this user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [sp_addsvrrolemember](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/grant-sysadmin-role-to-user) stored procedure:

```
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'MyDomain\MyUser', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```